# Adding years to a date resets to 1970-01-01

Tags: php, date, strtotime, dateadd

```
$somedate = "1980-02-15";
$otherdate = strtotime('+1 year', strtotime($somedate));
echo date('Y-m-d', $otherdate);
```

outputs

```
1981-02-15
```

and

```
$somedate = "1980-02-15";
$otherdate = strtotime('+2 year', strtotime($somedate));
echo date('Y-m-d', $otherdate);
```

outputs

```
1982-02-15
```

but

```
$somedate = "1980-02-15";
$otherdate = strtotime('+75 year', strtotime($somedate));
echo date('Y-m-d', $otherdate);
```

outputs

```
1970-01-01
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the [2038 bug](http://www.2038bug.com/) which is like y2k where systems can't handle dates after that year due to 32 bit limitations. Use the [DateTime class](http://php.net/DateTime) instead which does work around this issue.

**For PHP 5.3+**

```
$date = new DateTime('1980-02-15');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P75Y'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

**For PHP 5.2**

```
$date = new DateTime('1980-02-15');
$date->modify('+75 year');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: how to add 75 years to a given string of "1980-02-15" using the datetime class?

Comment: Thanks. I get Fatal error: Call to undefined function date_add(). I am using PHP Version 5.2.17.

Comment: Ahh. This requires 5.3. Lemme see if I can find a 5.2 example.

Comment: Ok, found an alternative for PHP 5.2

Answer (score 4):

strtotime() uses a unix timestamp, so it overflows if it attempts to calculate years beyond 2038 and reverts back to 1970.

To get around this, use the DateTime object.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

To add a period of time to a DateTime object, use DateTime::add, which takes a DateInterval as a parameter.
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

```
$date = new DateTime("1980-02-15");
if (method_exists("DateTime", "add")) {
    $date->add(new DateInterval("Y75"));
} else {
    $date->modify("+75 years");
}
echo $date->format("Y-m-d");
```

Comment: how to add 75 years to a given string of "1980-02-15" using the datetime class?

Comment: Thanks. I get Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::add(). I am using PHP Version 5.2.17.

Comment: ::add is only in 5.3+.  You'll want to call ::modify on it with a string parameter alike one you would use for strtotime.

Answer (score 1):

For unix timestamp, the maximum representable time is 2038-01-19. At 03:14:07 UTC.

So you can't represent/operate time that over it by using timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's dates are limited to a range from 01-01-1970 to 19-01-2038.  You will have to use a different method for working with dates.

PEAR has a Date class : [PEAR Date](http://pear.php.net/package/Date/redirected)

Answer (score 0):

75 years from 1980 is 2055, which is past the highest date value that can be represented in a 32-bit integer. Therefore the result becomes 0, which is the 1970 date you observe.