# php - date reset to 1970 at 2038 while adding in a loop

Tags: php, datetime, year2038

I have been trying to generate a list of years and months based on some integer value provided by user in my PHP based web app. While doing this I faced the year 2038 bug, the year got reset to 1970 when the loop reached to 2038. The PHP version I am using is 5.4 and I googled and applied the solution found in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924849/adding-years-to-a-date-resets-to-1970-01-01), but it is not working for me, did anyone try some other solution for the 2038 bug in php?

Here is my PHP code:

```
 $i = 1;
 $Tenurein = 360;
 while ($i < $Tenurein) {
    $MonthArr[] = date('F', strtotime($date2));
    $YearArr[] = date('Y', strtotime($date2));
    $date = new DateTime($date2);
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
    $dateMon = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    $date2 = $dateMon;
    $i++;
}
```

.

Comment: This is a well known problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: correct, but is there any workaround in PHP to overcome this?

Comment: use `DateTime` objects, that can handle less / more then unix timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using php version 5.6. Below code producing output 
[View output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U5qR.png)

```
<?php
$i = 1;
 $Tenurein = 360;
 $date2 = date('Y-m-d');
 while ($i < $Tenurein) {
    $MonthArr[] = date('F', strtotime($date2));
    $YearArr[] = date('Y', strtotime($date2));
    $date = new DateTime($date2);
    $date->modify('+1 month');
    echo $dateMon = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    $date2 = $dateMon;
    $i++;
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

We could see lot of posts regarding this issue. For displaying date it seems there are no issues. But while storing in database i too faced same issue.  if you use timestamp data type just change as datetime. It will work.

Comment: problem is I missed to change `strtotime` to `DateTime` at some other places as well, now it is working, thanks.