# Change the format of dates before 1900 without using explode?

Tags: php, date

i am converting 'd-m-Y' format to 'Y-m-d'

Currently, I am using this code

```
$dp_date = '13-12-1901';
$formated_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($dp_date));
```

but not working with dates before 14-12-1901
and works fine after this date '13-12-1901' as input.

whats the problem here?
and how can i do this formatting for the dates before 1900, or 14-12-1901 to be specific?

Comment: Use DateTime objects, which support ranges well outside those of a unix timestamp, which will allow you to work with dateranges that a Paleobiologist or cosmologist would be happy with

Comment: @MarkBaker Just mentioned your answer to a similar question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known limitation of `Unix timestamp`.

As explained in php.net:

`strtotime()`

> The function expects to be given a string containing an English date
>   format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the
>   number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), relative to the
>   timestamp given in now, or the current time if now is not supplied.

BTW , if all you want to do is to replace the position of `d` and `Y` you can do
it with string manipulation.

**UPDATE**

> strtotime() has a range limit between Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 GMT
>   and Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT; although prior to PHP 5.1.0 this
>   range was limited from 01-01-1970 to 19-01-2038 on some operating
>   systems (Windows).

@MarkBaker
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2872094/998096

He suggested "using PHP's datetime objects which can work with a much wider range of dates".

Comment: The OP specifically states that he doesn't want to use `explode()`.

Comment: @AmalMurali - You're right , I was so focused in the content that I've missed the title.

Comment: ask you one thing,you say that it calsulate 'the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC)' then how it works with date before January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC, if it was a stupid question from me.just answer politely. :)

Comment: Updated the answer. I hope this one will help.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use PHP's [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) class (PHP 5.3+). It's a lot better and is known to work with a wider range of dates.

An example:

```
$dp_date = '13-12-1901';
$date = new DateTime($dp_date);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

should output:

```
1901-12-13
```

**[Demo!](https://eval.in/46505)**

Comment: should output 1901-12-13

Comment: @SobinAugustine: It was a typo. I've updated the answer with the *actual* output.